# why my field field does not want to appear in my link menu?

Tags: module, hyperlink, drupal-8

I would like to add an image type field (QR code precisely) in my edit link menu.
For this: I added and installed the module: Menu Item Extras (which allows to do that).
however, when I create my field in manage field, it does not want to be displayed.
In "manage display", it is not disabled.
what did I forget?

[her my field created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ4nJ.png)

[manage form display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XykI.png)

Comment: May you also put a screenshot of the "Manage form display" tab ?

Comment: I added it above:D